# DataGridView.DataSource from DataSet.ReadXml using array

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, dataset, dataview

I have below solution of loading xml file content into DataGridView which is working fine

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
this.dataGridView1.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Columns["name"].DisplayIndex = 0;
this.dataGridView1.Columns["party"].Width = 35;
...
```

Now I would like to pass only rows for some particular id's and this is working fine as well returning row with id = 2

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
DataView dv;
dv = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0], "id = 2 ", "id Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

However, I wish for id's to be returned from an Array and below won't work

```
int[] myArray;
myArray = new int[2] {2,10};

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
DataView dv;
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Count(); i++)
{
   dv = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0], "id in (myArray[i]) ", "id Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

I receive error "Use of unassigned local variable 'dv' "

what is wrong?

XML file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Recipies>
 <Recipe id="1" name="test1" party="false">
 <Recipe id="2" name="test2" party="true">
 <Recipe id="3" name="test3" party="false">
 <Recipe id="4" name="test4" party="false">
 <Recipe id="5" name="test5" party="true">
 <Recipe id="6" name="test6" party="false">
 <Recipe id="7" name="test7" party="false">
 <Recipe id="8" name="test8" party="true">
 <Recipe id="9" name="test9" party="false">
 <Recipe id="10" name="test10" party="true">
</Recipies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you've not put any values into myArray. Therefore myArray.Count() will be -1 and so won't enter into the for loop. This means nothing is assigned to dv and when you try and use it with the DataSource you get an error.

On a side note I think it's marginally less expensive to use myArray.Length rather than myArray.Count().

Comment: Value for myArray is being passed from other form dynamically. It exists.
For tests you can just add a few integers:
myArray [0] = 2;
myArray [1] = 10;
etc.

Comment: @Prime -  so when you debug, which line is giving you the error?

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

Comment: @Prime in which case it's most likely not entering the if loop. Can you debug and confirm that?

Comment: Error occurs when I start the app so I cant debug. 

I've tried to move dataGridView1.DataSource = dv; into for loop and then the error is "Syntax error: Missing operand after '[i]' operator. "

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
int[] myArray;
myArray = new int[2] {2,10};

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
DataView dv = null;
string RecipeIDConcatenate = string.Join(",", myArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());    
dv = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0], "id in ( " + RecipeIDConcatenate + ")", "id Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```